# iTunes ITL binary file format

Tags: itunes, music

Does anyone out there have information about the iTunes ITL file format?

I have found a document on CPAN that describes the format as it was 4-5 years ago, however it seems to have changed in recent years.  I'm currently using iTunes 8.

I'd like to know so I could update the "Date Added" attribute (amongst others) for my music files. Every time I move my music collection to a new computer, attributes such as Date Added seem to get reset to that date.  This is on WIndows XP.

I've downloaded the latest COM API for iTunes, but "Date Added" is readonly as are many others.

The iTunes XML library file can be edited, but the changes are over-written from the ITL file each time iTunes is run.

I've had a look at the ITL file in a Hex editor, and I can interpret the first few bytes of the header file, but I have a feeling it might actually use encryption on the remainder of the file.

Any ideas / links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://www.marteydodoo.com/2005/07/27/all-roads-lead-to-com-an-itunes-story/) relates an experience with changing the Playcounts in iTunes, maybe it can be of use to you.

Answer (score 7):

The [`titl`](http://code.google.com/p/titl/) project seems to have addressed this issue. Works as of iTunes 9.0.2.